# How to show volume controls in a video tag?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

code :

```
<video controls playsinline>
  <source src="url.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Before Chrome 67, there was a volume control so the user could move up or move down the volume:

[image: before Chrome 67]

And since Chrome 67, the user is only able to mute or unmute the volume :
[image]

I need it because it is for use on big touch screen where physical volume buttons are not available...

It could have been on `controlslist`, but the only available values are `nofullscreen nodownload noremoteplayback`, there isn't a `volumeslider`

So how to bring back the volume control that was in Chrome 66? Maybe some CSS, JS or HTML5 could help me?

Comment: Please provide the code.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly enough, the best solution I found is using something like Plyr https://github.com/sampotts/plyr.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.3.23/plyr.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.3.23/plyr.polyfilled.min.js"></script>

<video class="presentation_video_src" id="player2"  playsinline controls>
    <source src="/static/videos/intro2.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Currently the only major browser suffering from this self-inflicted bug is Chrome, so you could also add this check in javascript `!!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore` and insert the script & css dynamically only if it resolves to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by changing the browser settings.
which can be accessed using [chrome://flags/#enable-modern-media-controls.](http://chrome://flags/#enable-modern-media-controls.)

Answer (score -1):

Tentatively, you can back old UI.

Access to chrome://flags/#enable-modern-media-controls. and disabled "New Media Controls" and restart Chrome.

Comment: What if the OP is writing an app that will be used by thousands of users? Will every user have to switch to the old UI?